# Renaming libcrypto and libssl

Tags: gcc, makefile, openssl, libcrypto, libssl

I am trying to compile openSSL such that I can rename the target libraries, i,e. libssl and libcrypto to something like libssl_my and libcrypto_my.

For that I tried following:

1. Changed few flags like `"SHARED_CRYPTO"`, `"SHARED_SSL"`, `libcrypto$(SHLIB_EXT)` etc in openSSL Makefile but it is not taking any effect. Is it possible to change the Lib name from Makefile and if yes, What are the changes I should look for ?
2. Used patchelf to patch the SONAME of libcrypto and libssl and it worked but libssl is still searching for libcrypto.so.0.o. And it looks like we can not change dependent library name in libssl by patchelf. If there is a way to do, please let me know.

Comment: I tried patchelf with --replace-needed for 2nd option and now libssl is able to find renamed libcrypto

Comment: Although with patchelf ldconfig will complain that library is truncated as patchelf changes/add entries in .dynstr. It will be helpful if someone can help in 1st approach.

Answer (score 0):

we can replace the following strings in Makefile

1. replace "libssl" to "libmy_ssl"
2. replace "libcrypto" to "libmy_crypto"
3. replace "-lssl" to "-lmy_ssl"
4. replace "-lcrypto" to "-lmy_crypto"

for 1.1.1 source codes tree, take care the below two rules , keep the taget name as libcrypto.num and libssl.num

1. libmy_crypto.map: util/mkdef.pl util/libcrypto.num
2. libmy_ssl.map: util/mkdef.pl util/libssl.num

have a try, good luck!